# Multiple tap issue in navigation view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am using Navigation view. Initially it has one item(view) that contains a button. On tapping this button, a second view pushes in the navigation view. If the user intentionally or by accident double tap the button, it pushes second view two times. How can i solve this problem?

I have tried the buffer configuration as specified in this link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/events but problem with this solution is that it invokes the listener after the buffer time even on the first tap.

Here is sample code to demonstrate the issue.

Navigation View

```
Ext.define('Many.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'main',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'firstView'
            }           
        ]
    }
});
```

First View

```
Ext.define('Many.view.FirstView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'firstView',
    config: {
        title: 'First View',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                id:'myButton',
                text: 'Push Second View'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Second View

```
Ext.define('Many.view.SecondView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'secondView',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Second View'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Controller

```
Ext.define('Many.controller.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config : {
        refs : {
            myNavigationView : 'main',
            myButton :'main #myButton'
        },
        control : {
            myButton : {
                tap : 'pushSecondView'
            }
        }
    },
    pushSecondView: function () {
        var secondView = Ext.create('Many.view.SecondView');
        this.getMyNavigationView().push(secondView);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition whether that view exists in the viewport or not.

Add a reference in the `controller` like this:-

```
refs : {
            myNavigationView : 'main',
            myButton :'main #myButton',
            secondView : 'secondView'
        }
```

And add the condition:-

```
pushSecondView: function () {
     if(!this.getSecondView()){
        var secondView = Ext.create('Many.view.SecondView');
        this.getMyNavigationView().push(secondView);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks but what about other actions for example if i perform a server call  or validation on button tap, should i check some other condition or is there any other solution?

Comment: Well it depends on the scenario. But i dont think there is any specific solution by sencha itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```js
    /**
  * This method will be called from every item in the app that can be double tapped to push multiple items.
  * 
  * @returns {Boolean}
  */
 ENSURE_NO_DOUBLE_TAP : function(classNameToPush) {
  if (Ext.getClassName(Ext.getCmp('navigationview').getActiveItem()) == classNameToPush) {
   console.log("Prevented DoubleTap.");
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }
```

Then from any controller that uses navigationView.push({'theViewImPushing'}):

```js
  if (!ENSURE_NO_DOUBLE_TAP('App.view.TheViewImPushing')) {
   return;
  }
```

I keep a Statics singleton class around to call the ENSURE_NO_DOUBLE_TAP method from...but you could use it wherever fits.